# Conversion of nfa with self-loop to one without self-loop

Tags: automata, finite-automata, nondeterminism

For every nondeterministic finite state automata that has self-loop(s), there exists an equivalent NFA that does not have any self-loop. How can we prove this statement in a general basis without the use of examples?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for a solution without $\epsilon$-transitions you can simply do this: create a NFA in which every original state $q$ two copies $(q, 0)$ and $(q, 1)$.

If a state was final then both its copies are final. If $q_0$ was the initial state, then $(q_0, 0)$ is the new initial state. 
Create the transition function as follows: if there was a transition $q \to^a q'$, then add the two new transitions $(q, 0) \to^a (q', 1)$ and $(q, 1) \to^a (q', 0)$.

It is easy to see that his NFA is equivalent to the initial one. You have essentially created a DFA which is a bipartite graph, and each transition changes the side of the bipartition the current state is in.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new state and make the self loop point to the new state and add a empty transition from the new state back to the original state.

It is straightforward to prove that this NFA is equivalent to the original.

Comment: Empty transitions are not allowed in all definitions of NFA. There is a solution that does not introduce such $\varepsilon$-transitions. Actually, it works for deterministic automata too.

Answer (score 0):

Say that a state $q$ has a self loop on symbol $\alpha$, create a new state $q'$ and remove the self loop from $q$.

Then

1. let $q$ and $q'$ have the same transitions,
2. if in $q$ on reading $\alpha$ go to $q'$, if in $q'$ on reading $\alpha$ go to $q$,
3. if $q$ is an accept state let $q'$ be also an accept state.

If we are in $q$ and we read $\alpha$ we go to $q'$, if we are in $q'$ and we read $\alpha$ we go to $q$ so point 2 replaces the self loop. If we are in $q$ or $q'$ and we read any symbol we go to the same state since both have the same transitions that is what point 1 does, and if $q$ is accepting then so is $q'$.

Formally :

For a state $q$ with a self loop on symbol $\alpha$:

Create a new state $q'$.

Remove $\delta(q,\alpha) = q$

Then for each transition $\delta(q,\upsilon) = s$, where $s \in Q$, and $\upsilon\in\Sigma$, add transition $\delta(q'\upsilon) = s$.

Add transitions $\delta(q,\alpha) = q'$ and $\delta(q',\alpha) = q$.

If $q \in F$, where $F$ is the set of accept states, then let $q' \in F$.